# How to replace placeholder letter in URL?

Tags: ios, swift, url, alamofire

I have the URL to there I send my requests to get the results:

```
let URL = "https://api.myweb.site/search/\(searchText)"
```

but when my searchText contains a placeholder letter my app crashes. By the way, I'm using Alamofire.

How can I make my URL safe and avoid the crash? I've tried this:

```
let escapedString = searchText.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
```

but it crashes again. What is the solution for my problem?

Comment: i though alamofire have their own url check and encoding? maybe u can try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
let newURL:String = oldURL.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
```